# PHP SQL join (Select) not working on new server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have recently upgraded my development computer to an M1 pro. I have multiple errors coming up with the same code and same php version using MAMP when working on my new Mac.

I have narrowed down the code to a join (select) statement although cannot find the issue. This query is critical to the website operation as it presents my regular clients by date due.

The troubled code is:

```
INNER JOIN
(SELECT address_id, min(service_frequency) AS MINFrequency, quote_id
FROM quotes
GROUP BY address_id) groupQT
```

This format is essential and find it very difficult to supplement with the same results.

Full code:

```
SELECT *
FROM quotes QT
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT address_id, min(service_frequency) AS MINFrequency, quote_id
    FROM quotes
    GROUP BY address_id) groupQT
ON QT.address_id = groupQT.address_id
AND QT.quote_id = groupQT.quote_id

LEFT JOIN addresses ON addresses.address_id=QT.address_id
LEFT JOIN clients ON addresses.client_id=clients.client_id
LEFT JOIN completed ON QT.address_id=completed.address_id WHERE completed_id IN (SELECT MAX(completed_id) FROM completed, bookings WHERE bookings.booking_id= completed.booking_id and service_id=QT.service_id  GROUP BY completed.address_id) 
AND (QT.service_frequency != 0)
ORDER BY completed.completed + interval MINFrequency week ASC
```

The code is valid SQL, although it doesn't seem to be running. Has anyone had the same issue. PHP 5.6, (once this issue is solved I will be formatting my code to 8)

Comment: You say this code generates an error. Are you willing to share what this error is?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The error is the returning of 0 results. Compared to the same code running on my other Mac. Same database, other code also works on the website. This however isn't the only error that has occurred running on M1. Is it possible that its not working properly due to the processor architecture?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (I'd expect a syntax error...)

Comment: No, SQL is SQL no matter where it's deployed (as long as it's on the same version of the same DBMS in each case, obviously).  Assuming that, the, most likely, the data in the database is different.

Comment: @jarlh I'm running Mysql with a phpmyadmin, same exact sql data transferred accross

Comment: P.S. How is this relevant to PHP? I assume you've tested the query in isolation, not just within your PHP application?

Comment: @ADyson Data is identical. Unless you know of any possible changes that occur when a DBMS gets upgraded?

Comment: I.e. different MySQL versions?

Comment: It shouldn't change the data no, but in some cases it could change the behaviour of the code.

Comment: @ADyson I have verified it using sql verifiers online. Although I will run the code inside the DBMS

Comment: Add quote_id to the GROUP BY clause, and see what happens.

Comment: What versions of MySQL did you upgrade from and to?

Comment: @ADyson changed from 5.5 - 5.7 as I'm still running the same version of php it runs the older version of phpmyadmin (dbms for mysql)

Comment: P.S. I can see some non-ANSI joins in one of your subqueries (`FROM completed, bookings`) ...not the cause of your problems but they should be modernised with INNER JOIN to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Terminology note: phpMyAdmin isn't a DBMS for MySQL. **MySQL** is the DBMS (database management system). phpMyAdmin is just one of several client-side tools which can be used to adminster a MySQL DBMS.

Comment: @jarlh Okay, that made the query work, but its doubling up on results. Can you explain why that came up with an error on one computer although not on another?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for the explanation of a DBMS :) Simple mistake

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html says _"Implementation for the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode has been made more sophisticated, to no longer reject deterministic queries that previously were rejected. In consequence, this mode is now enabled by default, to prohibit only nondeterministic queries containing expressions not guaranteed to be uniquely determined within a group."_ ...not saying I fully understand all possible consequences of this, but it could be relevant if you're having issues with GROUP BY, as queries with invalid GROUP BYs would now fail.

Comment: Always read the release notes etc when upgrading.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/ has an overview with lots of useful links.

Comment: @ADyson hmmm much frustration there. I guess this is a problem. Thank you for your help. I will take a read of that.

Comment: If you're desperate, you can turn the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY option off, but that's a short-term fix. Better to re-write the SQL in a compliant way. A bit more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: @ADyson I guess I'm going to have to try to find a fix in the code instead of turning the option off. Any tips?

Comment: It's very hard to write SQL queries without seeing sample data, specification and expected result. (That's my way of saying no, we don't have enough info).

Comment: @ADyson All good ahaha, thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading Mysql from version 5.5 - 5.7 they enabled `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` by default resulting in the group by requiring every selected element that had multiple rows with the same identity.

Instead of adding `quote_id` into the GROUP BY, I added `MAX(quote_id) as quote_id` which performed the same result as without the new sql_mode disabled.

[image]